# Parse JSON String and array with NSJSONSerialization issue?

Tags: objective-c, json, nsjsonserialization

This is the code i have so far

```
// Parse data using NSJSONSerialization
NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *JsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:myData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error: &error];
if(!JsonArray)
{
    NSLog(@"Error Parsing Data: %@", error);
}
else
{
    for(NSDictionary *event in JsonArray)
    {
        if([[event description] isEqualToString:@"error"])
        {
            // Get error number? I am confused by this part
            NSLog(@"Element: %@", [event objectForKey:@"error"]);
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"Element: %@", [event description]);
        }
    }
}
```

this is the JSON Data that parses correctly:

```
[{data string}, {data strings}]
```

This only gives me the string "error" and not the int as well:

```
{"error":0}
```

I am echoing this data from a PHP script if that helps any. Am i just doing it wrong, or did i miss something?

Comment: @H2CO3 sorry, thanks for the edit.

Comment: Apart from that: you want to examine if there is an object with the key `error` (i. e. `if (event[@"error"] != nil)`).

Comment: @H2CO3 I tried to use [event objectForKey ... but i got Sigabrt.

Comment: And what was the exception message? "I got `SIGABRT`" in itself is non-informative.

Comment: Sorry, let me paste it in the question

Comment: @H2CO3 this is what i get in console: http://pastebin.com/qEeQXx1N I also added some code into my question above.

Comment: See my answer. (Um. Having seen the error message, you could really have figured this out on your own...)

Comment: @H2CO3 yea, it has been a long day. Thanks for the answer. Also, why not use capital letters?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that when you receive an error, you get back an `NSDictionary` and not an `NSArray`. This should work:

```
if ([jsonObject isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
    // no error: enumerate objects as you described above
} else if ([jsonObject isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
    // error: obtain error code
    NSNumber *errCode = jsonObject[@"error"];
} else {
    // something bad's happening
}
```

Stylistic pieces of advice:

1. Don't call your object `JsonArray`, since it's not always an array. Call it `jsonObject`.
2. Don't start variable names with capital letters.

Comment: In your answer, could you explain why not to use capital letters? That would really help, let me try that.

Comment: @EliteGamer because it's a convention.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by that?

Comment: @EliteGamer Names starting with caps are used for naming classes in Objective-C. If you don't adhere to this, you'll confuse the people who read your code.

Comment: Also, one more thing. Where do i place the code? When i rename your values with mine, i get an error. Expected Method to read dictionary element not found. @H2CO3

Comment: @EliteGamer That doesn't mean you should unaccept my answer. ----- Obviously, you have to use the appropriate variable names (e. g. start by replacing `JsonArray` with `jsonObject`, etc.).

Comment: Sorry, @H2CO3 . I did do that, but i am still getting that same error.

Comment: @EliteGamer I guess. You are supposed to be able to resolve trivial compiler errors yourself. If you can't, feel free to ask another question.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40879/discussion-between-elite-gamer-and-h2co3)

Answer (score 0):

```
NSDictionary *jsonDic = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:myData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];
NSLog(@"jsonDic: %@", [jsonDic objectForKey:@"string"]);
```

Comment: can you try the above

Comment: @Parthi , he is correct. I will not have an error all the time.

Comment: Got it. You have mentioned about the error. Not gone through it !!

Comment: @Parthi that is fine. Basically, when there is not error, the first JSON will be echoed, but if there is one, i need to see that there is error string in the JSON, then get the error number.

Answer (score 0):

Would be great if you had posted the complete JSON document that you are trying to parse, because without that, there is absolutely no chance to figure out whether your code is anywhere near correct. The example [{data string}, {data strings}] that you gave is most definitely not a correct JSON document, so trying to parse it will return nil. {"error":0} is a dictionary with a single key "error" and a value 0. Having dictionaries with a single key is let's say unusual.

A JSON document contains either an array or object (using JSON terms) which will be turned either into an NSArray* or an NSDictionary*. You should know whether you expect an array or dictionary. If you expect an NSArray, check that [jsonObject isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]. If you expect an NSDictionary, check that [jsonObject isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]. If you don't do that then the wrong JSON document will either crash your app or produce total nonsense.

If you have an array then you will usually iterate through the elements of the array and handle each one in turn. If you have a dictionary you will usually look up keys that you know how to handle. What you are doing, iterating through an array of dictionaries, and checking for a dictionary with a key of "error", that's a very strange design of your JSON document.

And lookup what the "description" method does. "description" is what NSLog calls to find out what to print when it is asked to print an object. For an NSDictionary with a single key "error" and a value 0, it would return something like "error:0" which is of course not the same as "error".